# CNN high confidence on wrong classifications

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I've trained a CNN for alphanumeric digits classifcation on about 2M image samples.
The network is rather simple:

```
conv->relu->maxpool->conv->relu->maxpool->flatten->dense->relu->dense->softmax
```

Accuracy is very good, I get over 99% on the validation set, but what troubles me is the fact that the network's prediction confidence is always very high (98%+) even for samples that are misclassified.

I thought it could be a problem of overfitting, so I saved a checkpoint of the network every 2000 steps during training, but almost all of them show the same behaviour (saved for the first two checkpoints or so, where te network's accuracy is still not good enough).

I tried researching the problem, but I'm not even sure what's the most appropriate search query, so I didn't come up with much.
What other reasons might be for the network excessive confidence in its predictions?

Comment: All the misclassification are always high or just some ? Have you checked for the one you trained if the data is clean or not ? Sometime there is already misclassified data in the training set. Are you using MNIST ?

Comment: All misclassifications I tested have high confidence, but I did not do a systematic analysis on the ones from the validation set (I'll run one tomorrow and see what comes up there). No, I'm not using mnist, it's our own dataset of license plate numbers. While it's possible that there are a limited number of mislabeled samples, it's not more than 0.1% of the whole dataset

Answer (score 3):

This is a fairly common occurrence with neural network models. My answer here is a conjecture, but I suspect that the reason this occurs is related to the problem of adversarial examples. Neural networks tend to have very steep transitions between classes, so examples can be near the boundary between two classes, and yet be dramatically misclassified. Adversarial examples take advantage of that by finding small modifications to an image from class $a$ that cause it to be classified as class $b$.

From this perspective, the problem appears to be one of [regularization](/questions/tagged/regularization), but I don't think that anyone has a *great* sense of the specific sequence of steps to take so that ambiguous or unclear inputs are not strongly classified in any category.

Comment: That seems to be an instance of overfitting?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I don't think so. OP reports very high accuracy on the *holdout* data, implying that the model does generalize beyond the training set. Do you mean overfitting in a different sense?

Answer (score 2):

Excessive confidence implies one of two things: firstly it could mean your network is really good at isolating the correct prediction, but this is unlikely due to the still high confidence on incorrect classifications and the fact that the network isn't particularly deep; secondly it could mean that the weights to your last dense layer are incredibly high, which forces the predictions post softmax to effectively 'mute' all other classes but the one with highest confidence.

Introducing some regularisation in your dense layers such as L2 regularisation results in the penalizing large weights. This has the effect of preventing overfitting and overconfidence. This will increase your loss (because confidence will decrease slightly) but other metrics that use the hard predictions (such as accuracy) will not decrease.

The network may also benefit from some dropout, but start out with some light L2 regularisation in your dense layers (start out with a small L2 weight of 0.05 and then adjust from there based on cross validation).

Also on a side note, a validation accuracy of 99% is really high. Are you performing any data augmentation? And is that augmentation happening before or after the validation split, because if it's occurring before you will have fallen into the trap of data leakage. Make sure you always do the validation split before *any* preprocessing (except for removal of samples).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the original issue is now obsolete, but your suggestion to use L2 regularisation is good. About data augmentation, I don't remember right now if I used it or not, but either way it was definitely applied after the train/test split. I now believe I was saturating the softmax and I should have tried using some label smoothing.

Answer (score 1):

The modern deep Neural networks tend to be overconfident.
you can also consider computing uncertainty estimates along with the confidence.
https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.04599
https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.01474

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/304332)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [Bayesian Neural Network](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.07710)? This can be built based on the [TensorFlow Probability](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability) library. Here I found a [blog post](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/bayesian-neural-networks-3-bayesian-cnn-6ecd842eeff3) that describes how to do it with CNN.

BNN can consider two types of uncertainties, namely: Epistemic Uncertainty and Aleatoric Uncertainty.

1. Epistemic Uncertainty: This type of uncertainty occurs when your model lacks the necessary training data. So, the parameter estimation cannot be determined super confidently. Adding more data reduces this type of uncertainty.
2. Aleatoric Uncertainty: This type of uncertainty is introduced directly from the training data. What if your data itself is noisy? It can be due to labeling errors, or the data can naturally contain uncertainty, for example: when you are working with sensor data, for the same input, different outputs can be generated naturally due to some imperfection. No matter how many data samples you add, you are still in this type of uncertainty. So we have to make the model aware of this as well.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_quantification#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20uncertainty%20is%20often%20characterized%20in%20terms,sample%20drawn%20from%20a%20probability%20distribution%20will%20be.):

> In mathematics, uncertainty is often characterized in terms of a probability distribution. From that perspective, epistemic uncertainty means not being certain what the relevant probability distribution is, and aleatoric uncertainty means not being certain what a random sample drawn from a probability distribution will be.

With the help of BNN, you can make your model aware of both of them, such that it knows when it doesn't know and doesn't give any wrong prediction with embarrassingly high confidence.

But like any other system, it is not perfect. Following are the fallbacks I experienced while working with it:

- You should not keep an extremely high hope. But at least you can hope for a better uncertainty estimation than a regular Non-Bayesian Neural Network.
- It is slower than its Non-Bayesian counterpart.
- I worked on text classification with this type of network. What I found, this network is good at preventing high confidence for completely nonsensical utterings but it struggles if you intentionally generate some adversarial inputs like, for text classification, if you query the model with a valid but incomplete sentence (which as a human we understand that it is also an OOD, but BNN sometimes fails in this case).
- Some say you can [approximate BNN](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/68774/80430) with Dropout.